# How to use http request sessions in dart

Tags: flutter, http, dart, session-cookies

Im struggling to figure out how to use sessions in flutter. In python I can for example do something like this for logging in:

```
s = requests.Session()
data = {'username':'user','password':'pass'}
s.post("https://example.com/login, data=data )
```

I can then make any new requests with the authenticated session:

```
s.get("https://example.com/myprofile")
```

In dart I tried this, which works fine and logs me in:

```
Map <String,String> data = {'username':'user','password':'pass'};

var url = Uri.parse('https://example.com/login');
var response = await http.post(url, body: data);
```

How do I use the same session once I'm logged in?

I tried the following which obviously didnt work:

```
var response = await http.get(url);
```

Comment: With `Python` you can use `requests.Session()` and it stores the cookies sent in the `HTTP Response` autonomously. However, if you want to do the same with the `Dart http package` you need to implement it by yourself. Therefore, you should create a `Session class` with a `Header`  map. Then, you need to implement the `GET` and `POST` methods and update the `cookie` value inside the `Header` map every time you receive a response. Thus, you can make new requests based on the cookies stored in your `Header` map